# How to prevent a CSS Grid blowout?

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid

I have an issue - my CSS layout is messed up by filling it with content.

If I remove the 'p' tag from the HTML (inside: section with class="philosophy") my CSS layout works well - side margins appear on both sides of the screen as intended. 
When the 'p' tag is inserted again my side margins get smaller or disappear from the screen. How can I prevent this from happening?

How can I fix the problem?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* wrapper of the content */

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 11.6666667% repeat(12, minmax(0, 4, 47916667%))/*repeat(12, minmax(0, 86px))*/
  11.6666667%;
  column-gap: 2, 08333333%;
  /*40px*/
  grid-template-areas: "navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation" ". philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy ." ". newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork ." ". categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories ." ". testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials ." ". followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta ." "footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser" "copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright";
  grid-template-rows: 1235px 858px 1307px 230px 906px 608px 528px 1fr;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: turquoise;
  grid-area: navigation;
}

.philosophy {
  background-color: rgba(230, 45, 45, 0.50);
  grid-area: philosophy;
}

.philosophy_content {
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  /*any other value than visible*/
}

.newestWork {
  background-color: rgba(50, 115, 180, 0.50);
  grid-area: newestWork;
}

.categories {
  background-color: rgba(120, 230, 45, 0.50);
  grid-area: categories;
}

.testimonials {
  background-color: turquoise;
  grid-area: testimonials;
}

.followOnInsta {
  background-color: rgba(230, 45, 45, 0.50);
  grid-area: followOnInsta;
}

.footerBrowser {
  background-color: rgba(50, 115, 180, 0.50);
  grid-area: footerBrowser;
}

.copyright {
  background-color: rgba(120, 230, 45, 0.50);
  grid-area: copyright;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /*.navigation {
                background-color: pink;
            }*/
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-areas: "navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation" ". philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy ." ". newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork ." ". categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories ." ". testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials ." ". followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta ." "footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser" "copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright"
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  /*480px*/
  /*.navigation {
                background-color: yellow;
            }*/
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-areas: "navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation" "philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy" "newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork" "categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories" "testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials" "followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta" "footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser" "copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright"
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="BG_gradient">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <section class="navigation">
      navigation
    </section>
    <section class="philosophy">
      <div class="philosophy_content">
        <img alt="philosophy img" />
        <h1>Látásmódom</h1>
        <h2>Őszinte képvilág</h2>

        <!--If I remove this <p> tag my css layout works. When the <p> tag is inserted my side margins get smaller or diappear from screen. How can I fix this problem?-->
        <!p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </p>

        <h2>Tudj meg többet</h2>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="newestWork">
      newestWork
    </section>
    <section class="categories">
      categories
    </section>
    <section class="testimonials">
      testimonials
    </section>
    <section class="followOnInsta">
      followOnInsta
    </section>
    <section class="footerBrowser">
      footerBrowser
    </section>
    <section class="copyright">
      copyright
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A good place to start in debugging this code would be in the CSS `.wrapper` declaration. Both `grid-template-columns` and `column-gap` contain syntax errors and are invalid.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.` instead of `,` in the numbers with floating dot. Like this

```
grid-template-columns: 
            11.6666667%
            repeat(12, minmax(0, 4.47916667%)) 
            11.6666667%
        ;
        column-gap: 2.08333333%;
```

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    /* wrapper of the content */
    .wrapper {
        height: 100vh;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 
            11.6666667%
            repeat(12, minmax(0, 4.47916667%)) 
            11.6666667%
        ;
        column-gap: 2.08333333%; 

        grid-template-areas:
          "navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation"
          ". philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy ."
          ". newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork ."
          ". categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories ."
          ". testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials ."
          ". followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta ."
          "footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser"
          "copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright"
        ;

        grid-template-rows:
            1235px
            858px
            1307px
            230px
            906px
            608px
            528px
            1fr
        ; 
    }

    .navigation {
        background-color: turquoise;
        grid-area: navigation;
    }

    .philosophy {
        background-color: rgba(230,45,45,0.50);
        grid-area: philosophy;
    }

    .philosophy_content {
        min-width: 0;
        overflow: auto; /*any other value than visible*/
    }

    .newestWork {
        background-color: rgba(50,115,180,0.50);
        grid-area: newestWork;
    }

    .categories {
        background-color: rgba(120,230,45,0.50);
        grid-area: categories;
    }

    .testimonials {
        background-color: turquoise;
        grid-area: testimonials;
    }

    .followOnInsta {
        background-color: rgba(230,45,45,0.50);
        grid-area: followOnInsta;
    }

    .footerBrowser {
        background-color: rgba(50,115,180,0.50);
        grid-area: footerBrowser;
    }

    .copyright {
        background-color: rgba(120,230,45,0.50);
        grid-area: copyright;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        /*.navigation {
            background-color: pink;
        }*/

        .wrapper {
            grid-template-areas: 
            "navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation"
            ". philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy ."
            ". newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork ."
            ". categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories ."
            ". testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials ."
            ". followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta ."
            "footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser"
            "copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright"
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 360px) { /*480px*/
        /*.navigation {
            background-color: yellow;
        }*/

        .wrapper {
            grid-template-areas: 
                "navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation"
                "philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy philosophy"
                "newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork newestWork"
                "categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories categories"
                "testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials testimonials"
                "followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta followOnInsta"
                "footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser footerBrowser"
                "copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright copyright"
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Photography</title>

  <meta name="keywords" content="portfolio, homepage" />
  <meta name="description" content="portfolio" />
  <meta name="author" content="Burjan Erno" />
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">


  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="BG_gradient">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <section class="navigation">
        navigation
      </section>
      <section class="philosophy">
        <div class="philosophy_content">
          <img alt="philosophy img" />
          <h1>Látásmódom</h1>
          <h2>Őszinte képvilág</h2>

          <!--If I remove this <p> tag my css layout works. When the <p> tag is inserted my side margins get smaller or diappear from screen. How can I fix this problem?-->
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          </p>

          <h2>Tudj meg többet</h2>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="newestWork">
        newestWork
      </section>
      <section class="categories">
        categories
      </section>
      <section class="testimonials">
        testimonials
      </section>
      <section class="followOnInsta">
        followOnInsta
      </section>
      <section class="footerBrowser">
        footerBrowser
      </section>
      <section class="copyright">
        copyright
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```